# Copy and paste from google translation

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-translate

Since this morning, I can no longer copy/paste the text translated by google translation.
I tried for several browser and the only one that works is chrome & chromuim

The only solution to copy/paste the translation on the other the browser is to disable the javascript browser.

Anyone have additional information?

Comment: did you checked if some error appears in console?

Comment: Have you tried killing all instances of the browser and restarting?

Comment: @Ispuk, yes, [here is console](http://front1.monsterup.com/upload/1351766751681.png) (firefox), but I do not see anything special

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I try, but the problem is the same! the only way is to copy the text to use chrome!

Comment: eheh strange you should delete cache and disable add-ons to find out if is a real problem, i think :P

Comment: @Ispuk all add-ons are disable, cache is empty... impossible to cut and paste! this is crazy.... I'll "try" to find out which piece of code block copy/paste

Comment: strange i have no problems on all browsers, keyboard and mouse both copying and pasting, i think you have somenthing that blocks someother thing :P

Comment: lol ^^ my mouse works very well as I can do copy and paste on google chrome. This mean that google has block all browser except his. :/

Comment: Solution: You can set the Boolean pref dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled pref to false on the about:config page.

Comment: @ujjain, `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` is already on false.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ctrl + C" works, if you hold it for 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: it does not work! I reboot windows to test and the result is the same

Comment: Apparently I'm not the only one with the problem! [See here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-translate-general/CimFeeM_WNI)